# Default document not working on Azure website

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have an ASP.NET website that I'm hosing on Azure websites with Framework 4.5. I have mentioned all the settings regarding default documents but I am getting **Http 500 error** whenever I hit the URL.

My default document is "**Default.aspx**" and I specify this in web.config as follows:

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="Default.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Even in Azure configuration settings I have mentioned the Default.aspx as a default document but it's not at all working. With local IIS publish the same thing is working but not on azure.

Comment: Are you able to access any other page in your website?

Comment: Hi Gaurav,
There is no issue with access. I am able to access all the pages. Just by default my site is not getting redirected to default.aspx.

Comment: You can try by setting `<customErrors mode="off"/>` and see the error details rather than the generic 500 error. More info on `customErrors` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: we are getting 500 error with no error on not even on our application log. Its not getting any default page while hitting on our site so its not rendering any page.